# Is there a way to break a program after it reaches a certain number of frames?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am trying to implement a recursive tree function and I am getting a segfault because the function calls itself over and I would like to see what state my program is at the end.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: The fact that the function calls itself is the point of a recursive function. I do not get your problem.

Comment: You might have some stack overflow. Show an [mre] in your question

Comment: GDB should catch a stackoverflow and automatically pause the program for you.

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to see what state my program is at the end.

Run the program under GDB, and it will stop (when your program exhausts its stack) and *show* you the state at the end.

Example:

```c
void fn(int j)
{
  char buf[1024];  // consume some stack space.
  buf[0] = 'a';
  fn(j - buf[0]);  // bad recursion -- should have checked for j - 'a' > 0
}

int main()
{
  fn(10000);
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g t.c && gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555130 in fn (j=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fef8c>) at t.c:2
2       {
(gdb) bt 10
#0  0x0000555555555130 in fn (j=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff7fef8c>) at t.c:2
#1  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759889) at t.c:5
#2  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759792) at t.c:5
#3  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759695) at t.c:5
#4  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759598) at t.c:5
#5  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759501) at t.c:5
#6  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759404) at t.c:5
#7  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759307) at t.c:5
#8  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759210) at t.c:5
#9  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=-759113) at t.c:5
(More stack frames follow...)
```

What you see here is the *state* of the program at the end, i.e. *exactly* what you asked for in the body of your question, but not in the title (it's a bad form to ask *different* questions in the body and the title).

> Is there a way to break a program after it reaches a certain number of frames?

There is not, but there are various approximations.

For the case of the test program above, the answer is trivial. Since `fn` keeps calling itself, you can stop on Nth call. E.g. if you want to stop when recursion reaches 100 frames, do this:

```
(gdb) b fn
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1136: file t.c, line 4.
(gdb) ign 1 100
Will ignore next 100 crossings of breakpoint 1.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, fn (j=300) at t.c:4
4         buf[0] = 'a';
(gdb) bt
#0  fn (j=300) at t.c:4
#1  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=397) at t.c:5
#2  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=494) at t.c:5
#3  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=591) at t.c:5
#4  0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=688) at t.c:5
...
#99 0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=9903) at t.c:5
#100 0x0000555555555158 in fn (j=10000) at t.c:5
#101 0x0000555555555169 in main () at t.c:10
```

Things get more complicated when `fn` calls itself indirectly (but if the cycle is of fixed length K, then just divide N by K).

If the cycle is not of fixed length, or if some of the calls return (i.e. not every call recurs), then getting to N levels deep is bit more complicated. The easiest way to do that is to modify the program to keep recursion count in a global. Then you can simply set a conditional watch point. Example:

```c
int recursion_count;

void fn(int j)
{
  char buf[1024];  // consume some stack space.

  recursion_count += 1;
  buf[0] = 'a';
  fn(j - buf[0]);  // bad recursion -- should have checked for j - 'a' > 0
  recursion_count -= 1;
}

int main()
{
  fn(10000);
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g t.c && gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x55555555517d: file t.c, line 15.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.c:15
15        fn(10000);
(gdb) p recursion_count
$1 = 0
(gdb) watch recursion_count
Hardware watchpoint 2: recursion_count
(gdb) cond 2 recursion_count == 100
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: recursion_count

Old value = 99
New value = 100
fn (j=397) at t.c:8
8         buf[0] = 'a';
(gdb) bt 
#0  fn (j=397) at t.c:8
#1  0x0000555555555167 in fn (j=494) at t.c:9
#2  0x0000555555555167 in fn (j=591) at t.c:9
#3  0x0000555555555167 in fn (j=688) at t.c:9
...
#97 0x0000555555555167 in fn (j=9806) at t.c:9
#98 0x0000555555555167 in fn (j=9903) at t.c:9
#99 0x0000555555555167 in fn (j=10000) at t.c:9
#100 0x0000555555555187 in main () at t.c:15
```

Voila.